# Translation of "genus" to Portuguese

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, notation, terminology, translation-request

Does somebody know of a translation to Portuguese for "genus" in topology?

> Theorem: A nonsingular projective curve in $\mathbb{P}_2$ is topologically a sphere with $g$ handles.
>
> Definition: This number $g$ is called the *genus* of the curve.

Comment: [There you go](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9nero_%28matem%C3%A1tica%29). I first translated it to Hebrew, and then to Portuguese.

Comment: Did you look at Wikipedia? http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Género_(matemática)

Answer (score 3):

CW answer from comments to push it from unanswered queue:

It is Género (form [Portuguese Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9nero_%28matem%C3%A1tica%29).)